# if loop stopping and not working

Tags: javascript

```
if (skin_var == 1) {
        skin = "%kraken";

        skin_var = 2;
    }
    if (skin_var == 2) {
        // this won't activate
        skin = "%mercury";

        skin_var = 3;
    }
    if (skin_var == 3) {
        skin = "%shark";

        skin_var = 4;
    }
    if (skin_var == 4) {
        // this won't activate either
        skin = "%banana";

        skin_var = 5;
    }
    if (skin_var == 5) {
        skin = "%nuclear";

        skin_var = 6;
    }
    if (skin_var == 6) {
        skin = "%space_dog";

        skin_var = 7;
    }
    if (skin_var == 7) {
        skin = "%t_rex"

        skin_var = 8;
    }
    if (skin_var == 8) {
        // gets stuck right here
        skin = "%spy"

        skin_var = 1;
    }
```

That's my code above. As you can see by the commented lines, they always don't work or get stuck at some point. Is there an efficient way to do this or a way to fix it?

I just want to change the skin to something every second forever, and I have used setInterval(); but it only seems to do "%kraken" to "%shark" to "%nuclear" to "%t_rex" and then it cycles before I added "%spy".

Comment: What is an "if loop"? There's no loop here. What does "it gets stuck" mean? Did you debug?

Comment: Use if-else conditionals or the result will always be skin = "%spy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Instead of switch or if statement I made an array with all values
var values = ["%kraken", "%mercury", "%shark", "%banana", "%nuclear", "%space_dog", "%t_rex", "%spy"];

var i = 0;

// Foreach loop I set a different value to skin variable, with the i value. When i variable is great than values' length I set it to zero (interval is 1000 millisecond)
setInterval(function(){ 
    if (i > values.length -1) {
        i = 0;
    }
    skin = values[i];
    i++;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm try to conserver the code that you already have made adding the setInterval and using the operator % to make that the value of skin_val var always stay in the range from 0 to 7

```
var skin_var = 0;
var skin;
function changeSkin(){
    if (skin_var == 0) {
    skin = "%kraken";
}
if (skin_var == 1) {
    // this won't activate
    skin = "%mercury";
}
if (skin_var == 2) {
    skin = "%shark";
}
if (skin_var == 3) {
    // this won't activate either
    skin = "%banana";
}
if (skin_var == 4) {
    skin = "%nuclear";
}
if (skin_var == 5) {
    skin = "%space_dog";
}
if (skin_var == 6) {
    skin = "%t_rex"
}
if (skin_var == 7) {
    // gets stuck right here
    skin = "%spy"
}
skin_var = (skin_var+1)%8
console.log(skin);
}
window.setInterval(changeSkin, 1000);
```

you can see the results in the console log.

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses a simple recursive `setTimeout` instead.

```
var skins = [
  '%kraken', '%mercury', '%shark', '%banana', '%nuclear', '%space_dog', '%t_rex', '%spy'
];

var skin;

function changeSkin(i) {
  skin = skins[i = i && i < skins.length ? i : 0];
  setTimeout(changeSkin, 1000, ++i);
}

changeSkin();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/em66gevs/1/)

Answer (score -1):

A `switch` will be more readable and more efficient than an `if` in your case. 
This allows you to only look up the `skin_var` value once as opposed to every time in your `if`.

This does what you are asking. Make sure your console is turned on when you run it.

```js
function changeSkin(){
  switch (skin_var){
    case 1: 
        skin = "%kraken";
        break;      
    case 2 : 
        skin = "%mercury";
        break;      
    case 3: 
        skin = "%shark";
        break;      
    case 4: 
        skin = "%banana";
        break;      
    case 5: 
        skin = "%nuclear";
        break;      
    case 6:
        skin = "%space_dog";
        break;      
    case 7:
        skin = "%t_rex"
        break;      
    case 8:
        skin = "%spy"
        skin_var = 0;
        break;
    default:
        skin_var = 0;
        break;
  }
  ++skin_var;
  console.log(skin);
}
var skin_var = 1;
setInterval(changeSkin, 1000)
```

Comment: Hmm... I'll try this